# Handler returning null pointer

Tags: java, android, multithreading, callback

I am trying to run the following code:

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {

private static class MyListLoadingCallback implements Handler.Callback {
    private ListActivity activity;
    private MyListManager myListManager;

    public MyListLoadingCallback(ListActivity activity,
            MyListManager articleListManager) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.myListManager = myListManager;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
        throw new NotYetImplementedException();
    }
}

private MyListManager myListManager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    myListManager.fetchArticles(new Handler(
            new MyListLoadingCallback(this, MyListManager)));

}
```

I am getting a Null pointer at articleListManager.fetchArticles(new Handler(new MyListLoadingCallback(this, MyListManager)));

My other class looks like the following:

```
public class MyListManager  {

    public void fetchArticles(final Handler handler) {
    }
}
```

Can someone please walk me / help me with this snippet of code for better understanding. I don't seem to fully understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems quite clear :).

There is only one "reference" being accessed in the line that's throwing the exception (`myListManager.fetchArticles(new Handler(new MyListLoadingCallback(this, MyListManager)));`) and it is `myListManager`, so it must be `NULL`. And looking at the code, you never initialize it to anything, so it is indeed `NULL` :)

Comment: I thought that this.myListManager = myListManager; is where we initalized myListManager, althought I am not sure, how would initialize it in this specific scenario for example?

Comment: myListManager = new MyListManager();